# How to use row value expressions in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

The jOOQ blog claims that it is one of [ten more common mistakes that Java developers make when writing SQL](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/08/12/10-more-common-mistakes-java-developers-make-when-writing-sql/) to not use row value expressions where they are supported.

Their recommendation is to issue SQL like the following (instead of chaining a couple of single-column conditions with AND):

```
SELECT c.address
FROM   customer c,
WHERE (c.first_name, c.last_name) = (?, ?)

SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, a.street
FROM   customer c
JOIN   address a
ON  (c.id, c.tenant_id) = (a.id, a.tenant_id)
```

But how do I actually code this in jOOQ?

Answer (score 1):

Short of language support for tuples / records in Java, you will need to use one of the many overloaded [`DSL.row()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row%28org.jooq.Field...%29) methods.

Your examples (from the question) would then translate to:

```java
// Assuming static imports:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.row;
import static your.generated.code.Tables.CUSTOMER;

Customer c = CUSTOMER.as("c");
Address a = ADDRESS.as("a");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(c.ADDRESS)
   .from(c)
   .where(row(c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME).eq("Jon", "Doe"))
   //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ <-> ^^^^^  ^^^^^ Types must match
   .fetch();

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME, a.STREET)
   .from(c)
   .join(a)
   .on(row(c.ID, c.TENANT_ID).eq(a.ID, a.TENANT_ID))
   //      ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ <-> ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ Types must match
   .fetch();
```

In the above example, [`Row2<T1, T2> DSL.row(Field<T1>, Field<T2>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row%28org.jooq.Field,%20org.jooq.Field%29) would be applicable and ensure that left and right hand side row value expressions are of the same degree and type.

Note that according to the SQL:1999 standard, `ROW` is an optional keyword to be used with `<row value constructor>`, i.e. `ROW(a, b)` is the same as `(a, b)`.